# Are there Romance parallel descendants to Italian "cicalare" and Romanian "cicăli(re)"?

Tags: etymology, latin, romance-languages, italian, romanian

I am looking for the etymology of the Romanian verb [*a cicăli*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cic%C4%83li) (to make reproaches repeatedly, to nag), which is reported of unknown origin, and I have found [an almost identical word in Italian: *cicalare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cicalare). (And I've asked [this](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/14553/5860) question).

It seems that Occitan has *cicala* as such, meaning "cicada", and it ended up in [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cicala#English) with the same form, also in French *cigale*. Spanish and Portuguese *cigarra* might come from a different intermediary (**cicār(r)*a)

Romanian too has [*cicoare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cicoare#Etymology_1), meaning "cicade", which appears as a diminutive form of a possible **cicară* (rhotacization of *cicala*). (Thus, it is formally identical (a homophone) of the much more commonly used [cicoare="chicory"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cicoare#Etymology_2) and might have been contaminated by it. It cannot be considered the origin of *cicăli* because the *l>r* shift is not inherited there.— In fact, *cicoară*=cicada might not even have to be of Latin origin: while Aromanian has *cingală*, closer to Italian and Latin, Megleno-Romanian *țicoari* is closer both to the Romanian and the Greek forms ζειγαρά, ζειγάρη —).

Romanian also has the rarely used noun [*cicală*](https://dexonline.ro/definitie/cical%C4%83) ("nagging, quarrelsome person", for which, oddly, unlike for the verb, an Italian connection is mentioned —but Italian *cicala* doesn't mean a nagging person). It looks more like the Romanian noun *cicală* is a back-formation from the verb *cicăli*.

I am looking for a similar word in other Romance languages with the same root and a similar meaning as those verbs in Romanian and Italian. — Does the late Latin, and/or early Medieval Latin word *[cicala](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cicala#Latin)* have other descendants in Romance languages with a similar meaning (to talk too much, make repeated statements/reproaches)?

(Or: if this question is better fit to Latin, please flag it or indicate so that I move it.)

---

UPDATE after chat(GP)ting a bit:

I get this info:

> In Spanish, the verb "chillar" can sometimes carry a similar meaning
> to "cicalare" or "cicăli," although it's more commonly used to
> describe the action of screaming or shouting loudly. However, it can
> also be used informally to describe someone who talks excessively or
> noisily.
>
> In Portuguese, the verb "chilrear" also exists... It's used to
> describe the chirping of birds but can also be applied metaphorically
> to describe people chatting or gossiping.

I think that's true. But they don't seem related to *cicada>cicala*. *Couldn't they be considered parallel constructions anyway?*
Semantically and formally they seem rather close to Italian *cicalare*, and their etymology is not very categorically proven, as onomatopoeic origin is suggested beside Latin **cistulāre<fistulāre* ... Even "cicada" is of [onomatopoeic origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cicada#Latin) it seems (Sanskrit *ciścira*, while English *to chirp* sounds almost like Romanian *a ciripi*). I can imagine a verb that is not necessarily based on the noun, but is just a parallel construction, naming the basic sound (be it bird on cicada).

Answer (score 2):

Spanish and Portuguese have the word cigarra, which also refers to the insect and ultimately comes from Latin (there is debate whether the Portuguese word is native or replaced its native word with the Spanish one), but no verb that comes from this noun.
Naturally, there are words in these languages that mean "nagging".

I recommend that you refer to actual dictionaries instead of Wikipedia, which is not edited by educated people. It is easy to use, but it is lazy.

Comment: Wiktionary is tricky, but can work as a stable basis of discussion. Stackexchange is also meant at improving or discussing Wikipedia and Wictionary articles, although its own articles are not always published by very educated people. The idea here is to educate each other. The information that Spanish and Portuguese have words for "nagging" is not very useful and not at all unexpected, but the one that they don't have verbs based on cicada/cicala with the discussed meaning is useful.

Comment: Wiktionary is absolutely edited by educated people. Not _exclusively_ so, but many of the people who contribute etymologies to Wiktionary are trained historical linguists who definitely know what they’re doing.

Comment: Oddly, Spanish has the word *chillar* and Portugues has  *chilrear*, related to bird sound, not cicadas. Semantically and formally they seem rather close to Italian *cicalare*, and their etymology is not very categorically proven, as onomatopoeic origin is suggested beside Latin  *cistulāre<fistulāre ... Even "cicada" is of onomatopoeic origin it seems, so I can imagine a verb that is not necessarily based on the noun, but is just a parallel construction, naming the basic sound (be it bird on cicada).

Answer (score 2):

I don’t have any particular sources for this, but this is too long for a comment, so it’ll have to go in an answer.

My *guess* (and it is only a guess) would be that Romanian has obtained the word for a cicada at least two, perhaps three times over:

- *Cicadă* is the most straightforward version: it corresponds exactly to the Classical Latin form, and it refers to the animal itself
- *Cicală* formally looks like a borrowing from some Romance form that substituted /l/ for /d/ in the word (a not-unheard-of change in Latin and Romance), which – if Wiktionary data is reliable here – appears to be a form that flourished especially in the eastern parts of the Latin-speaking world (including Italy)
- *Cicoare* may be the same as *cicală* with subsequent rhotacisation and influence from the ‘chicory’ word, both within Romanian; or it may be a loan from another Romance form with further rhotacised /l/ to /r/ (similar to the Iberian forms), with only the vowel qualities changing within Romanian based on the ‘chicory’ word

I’m not sure it’s really possible to neatly etymologise which is which in such a tangle of words (or even which are inherited and which borrowed) – onomatopoeia so often results in variations and derivations that seem to criss-cross and not fully correspond, and forms with /d/, /l/ and /r/ are found throughout the Romance-speaking area.

As for the meaning, it seems to be accepted that the noun *cicala* ‘cicada’ led to the Italian verb *cicalare* ‘chatter, jabber, gossip; say insistently’. This makes sense, based on the noise made by cicadas: it does sound like an insistant, constant, buzzing chatter.

I would venture that Romanian *a cicăli* must be based on *cicală* through a similar process. I’m guessing that formally, a fourth-declension verb in Romanian would not be the expected reflex of a borrowed first-declension Italian verb, so it’s not likely to be a direct borrowing of *cicalare*; but ‘nag, pester, reproach insistently’ is also quite a straightforward meaning for a verb derived from a noun referring to cicadas (swarms of cicadas are certainly a pestering nuisance to listen to), so I would posit that *a cicăli* was likely derived within Romanian.

As such, while parallel constructions in other Romance languages would certainly be nice additional data points, their absence is not necessarily highly significant.

Comment: *cicadă* is not in discussion here, but a recent cultured borrowing from French and Latinized formally. *Cicoare* is mysterious: there's Meglo-Romanian *țicoari*, close to a Greek *ζειγαρά, ζειγάρη*. Could be a Balkan form. But my main concern is the verbs, not the nouns. What baffled me is the identity of Romanian and Italian verbs and the fact that Romanian dictionaries ignore this.  *Cicală* ("nagging person") is most probably retroactively formed based on the verb, unlike in Italian. - Presence of similar verbs in Romance would comfort my idea that Romanian verb is inherited, not borrowed.

Comment: Unlike in Italian, what seems primary in Romanian is the verb. All nouns can be separated from it: one is a neologism, one is a back-formation, one may not even be related.

Comment: @cipricus What makes you say that the verb seems more primary than the noun rather than the other way around? Does Romanian not normally use the fourth declension for denominal derivatives or something? (I did assume that _cicadă_ was probably the most recent, since it’s the most transparent.)

Comment: I mean that "cicală", unlike the verb, is a very rare word and only means "nagging person", never "cicada", so I think it was formed later in Romanian based on the verb *cicăli*. So we cannot say that Romanian verb is based on a Romanian noun (in the way Italian verb is based on an Italian noun "cicala"). The Romanian verb stands alone, separate from *cicoare* (which might even be pre-Latin, that is of Balkan substrate, beside also being extremely rare and maybe also a regionalism —I didn't know it existed with this meaning until today! I though "cicoare" was just chicory!)

Comment: @cipricus The fact that the noun is rare and the verb isn’t doesn’t say anything about which was originally derived from which, though. There are lots of examples of rare words being the base for very common words. My suggestion is that _cicală_ was originally borrowed as ‘cicada’, whence ‘someone who makes an annoying cicada-like racket = a nagger’, whence the verb ‘act like a nagger = nag’. Subsequently, the original ‘cicada’ meaning was lost when that word was reborrowed, and the ‘nagger’ noun fell out of use, though the verb remained more common.

Comment: I have to agree with your main statement. It's just I personally (native and supposedly well-read Romanian speaker) had no idea about *cicală* either, until yesterday!... But I have to disagree in some detail. The neologism *cicadă* is too recent for the interaction you imagine with an older "cicada". There's  no need for "cicada" in Romanian: there was the proto-Romanian/proto-Italian pair *cicala/cicalare-cicală/cicăli(re)* and there was the (maybe "Dacian") form *cicoare*. Maybe because the latter was already present, 'cicala' lost its cicada meaning very fast.

Comment: By the way: Italian only has "cicala", not cicada. Cicala existed as such in late Latin, and that's what entered Italian, and maybe Romanian too, if Romanian word is not an Italian borrowing, and I think it's not. But it it is, it would be a later one compared to the rhotacised "cicoare/cicoară" (which, if Latin, would still come directly from "cicala": no need of a Romanian old "cicada" anyway, cicala>*cicara>cicoară is very natural Romanian mutation, because *-oară* is normal feminine and diminutive ending, like for *mioară*=sheep, *fecioară*=maiden, *surioară*=little sister etc).

Comment: @cipricus I’ll take your word for all the inner-Romanian stuff, since I don’t know much about Romanian. I take it if _-oară_ is a common feminine/diminutive ending, then only the change from _-oară_ to _-oare_ really requires any influence from the ‘chicory’ at all? (To be clear, I meant that _cicală_ had been borrowed with the original _meaning_ ‘cicada’, not that that was the _form_ that was borrowed.)

Comment: e/ă ending switch is not a problem at all, because it's a regional variation (Romanian has quasi-dialects). The homonym influence is seen as a possible alternative explanation why *cicala* didn't end up with a stable form *cicară*.